# How can I view my file in github repository?

Tags: github

In my github repository, I have the file site, and in the course I'm following, when he added site/ it opened for him the HTML page in the folder, but I am not able to do that, it just shows me error, I tried adding .html, its not showing. Can you please help?

[image: Here's what happens]

Comment: Are you sure that you have uploaded those files to the repository?

Comment: Did you read the text of that page? It's telling you that you need an index.html file at that path. Also, we're not following along with the same course, so we don't have the same context you do. Please [edit] your question to provide that context. Also, please take the [tour] and read [ask] to prevent further downvotes and question closures.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your [repository](https://developers.taboola.com/taboolasdk/v2/docs/taboola-widget-android-sdk), you have two branches:

- main
- gh-pages

You have uploaded your site folder and all relevant files on your **gh-pages** branch.

To see your Github page that you have created in your **gh-pages** branch, you first must publish it.

Please follow the documentation [here](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site).